# Who can legally arrest an on-duty law enforcement officer in NH?

Tags: police, arrest, new-hampshire, citizens-arrest

If a New Hampshire citizen sees a New Hampshire cop commit a state or federal felony, can a citizen *legally* effect a citizen's arrest? Can other LEOs (law enforcement officers) effect such an arrest? Does it matter if the offender LEO is a sheriff or corporate police officer?

---

Note: I know it's tempting to answer a different question: *Is it practical or advisable to arrest a LEO?*  Please note that is a different question.

This question is also different from [this](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/4255/placing-a-police-officer-under-citizens-arrest) question. My question is only concerned with the elements of a ***legal*** arrest in NH ***of LEOs***, not what an arrest per se is legally defined as and not what retaliation is legal for the LEO who is hypothetically under arrest.

Comment: Interesting question.

Comment: Also related: [Can a civilian legally take any action against a police officer if they witness the officer violating traffic laws?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/15438/10)

Comment: Here is an example to consider: https://youtu.be/hduf4twyROA. The officer is clearly committing assault and or battery, repeatedly and without any legal pretense.